# Why is the channel in the Datta-Das spin transitor a 2DEG?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In [the original proposal for the Datta-Das spin transistor](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.102730), it is assumed that carriers in the channel are a 2D electron gas, as shown in the picture below. Why would a 2DEG form at the InGaAs/InAlAs interface?

[image: dattadasdevice]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read ref. 9 in the paper linked.

It shows the heterostructure band alignments for the InAlAs/InGasAs interface. There is a quite a large conduction band offset between the two materials. This leads to sharp band bending over a small volume. This forms the 2DEG quantum well mentioned.

[image: Ref 9 band alignment]